# How to conditionally set cookie in location section depending on certain query parameter

Tags: nginx, cookies

Requests to various locations may contain a query parameter like `?ide_theme=dark`. Depending on its presence, I need to set a cookie `user_ide_theme` to the parameter value in Nginx. It's important to keep existing cookie if the parameter is absent in request.

The most intuitive way:

```
location ~ / {
    # ...

    if ($arg_ide_theme) {
        add_header Set-Cookie 'user_ide_theme=$arg_ide_theme;Path=/;HttpOnly';
    }

    # other locations
}
```

But it doesn't work and Nginx docs have more or less clear explanation [why if shouldn't be used here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

> The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in a location context are:
>
> - return ...;
> - rewrite ... last;

How can I add this header conditionally depending on a query parameter?

- a cookie shouldn't be cleared if a user already has it, but there is no such query parameter in request
- a cookie should be updated, if something new comes in the query parameter
- it's not necessary to keep this parameter in the request

The only workaround I found so far is to use redirect inside `if` to the same address, but without query parameter after setting a cookie - then it would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive for this:

```
map $arg_ide_theme $user_ide_theme {
    "~^(.+)$" "user_ide_theme=$1;Path=/;HttpOnly";
    default "";
}

server {
    ...
    add_header Set-Cookie $user_ide_theme;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this